# Can I define variable names in my word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am creating a document for that, can I define some text in a variable say:

```
var x = "USA"
```

and use this variable in my document instead of word USA. It will help me to change or say replace the text with the variable instances only and not the other text used for same.

say I have a paragraph

```
USA: The president of USA declares war against poverty.
```

**USA** (*this text is printed by variable and can be changed with changing variable value*):**The president of USA**(*this is static text and has no effect on variable value change*) **declares war against poverty.**

Comment: you could achieve something like this using bookmarks. I think VBA code will be necessary to make it efficiently, too.

Comment: Either SET fields and REF fields, Custom Document Properties and DOCPROPERTY fields, Document Variables (you need VBA to create them) and DOCVARIABLE fields, or in Windows Word 2007 and later, Content Controls connected to a custom XML data store. There's already plenty of material on those options in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively no. However you have a few options.

You could use a random string (e.g. "$country") as a placeholder, and then find-replace before you print.

Ms office also supports plugins to be written with VBA(visual basic for applications). Therefore you may be able to find or write a plugin for what you want to do